# Gradient Descent failing for multiple variables, results in NaN

Tags: machine-learning, octave, linear-regression, gradient-descent

I am trying to implement gradient descent algorithm to minimize a cost function for multiple linear algorithm. I am using the concepts explained in the machine learning class by Andrew Ng. I am using Octave. However when I try to execute the code it seems to fail to provide the solution as my theta values computes to "NaN". I have attached the cost function code and the gradient descent code. Can someone please help.

**Cost function :**

```
function J = computeCostMulti(X, y, theta)

m = length(y); % number of training examples

J = 0;

h=(X*theta);
s= sum((h-y).^2);
J= s/(2*m);
```

**Gradient Descent Code:**

```
function [theta, J_history] = gradientDescentMulti(X, y, theta, alpha, num_iters)

m = length(y); % number of training examples
J_history = zeros(num_iters, 1);

for iter = 1:num_iters

  a= X*theta -y;
  b = alpha*(X'*a);
  theta = theta - (b/m);

  J_history(iter) = computeCostMulti(X, y, theta);  
end
```

Comment: Sure will do as you suggested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did found the bug and  it was not either in the logic of the cost function or gradient descent function. But indeed in the feature normilization logic and I was accidentally returning the wrong varible and hence it was cauing the output to be "NaN"

It is dumb mistake :

What I was doing previously

```
mu= mean(a);
sigma = std(a);
b=(X.-mu);
X= b./sigma;
```

Instead what I shoul be doing

```
function [X_norm, mu, sigma] = featureNormalize(X)
%FEATURENORMALIZE Normalizes the features in X 
%   FEATURENORMALIZE(X) returns a normalized version of X where
%   the mean value of each feature is 0 and the standard deviation
%   is 1. This is often a good preprocessing step to do when
%   working with learning algorithms.

% You need to set these values correctly
X_norm = X;
mu = zeros(1, size(X, 2));
sigma = zeros(1, size(X, 2));

% ====================== YOUR CODE HERE ======================


mu= mean(X);
sigma = std(X);
a=(X.-mu);
X_norm= a./sigma;

% ============================================================

end
```

So clearly I should be using X_norm insated of X and that is what cauing the code to give wrong output

Answer (score 2):

I implemented this algorithm in GNU Octave and I separated this into 2 different functions, first you need to define a gradient function

```
function [thetaNew] = compute_gradient (X, y, theta, m)
    thetaNew = (X'*(X*theta'-y))*1/m;
end
```

then to compute the gradient descent algorithm use a different function

```
function [theta] = gd (X, y, alpha, num_iters)
    theta = zeros(1,columns(X));
    for iter = 1:num_iters,
        theta = theta - alpha*compute_gradient(X,y,theta,rows(y))';                
    end
end
```

**Edit 1**
This algorithm works for both multiple linear regression (multiple independent variable) and linear regression of 1 independent variable, I tested this with this dataset

```
age height  weight
41  62  115
21  62  140
31  62  125
21  64  125
31  64  145
41  64  135
41  72  165
31  72  190
21  72  175
31  66  150
31  66  155
21  64  140
```

For this example we want to predict

```
predicted weight = theta0 + theta1*age + theta2*height
```

I used these input values for alpha and num_iters

```
alpha=0.00037
num_iters=3000000
```

The output of runing gradient descent for this experiment is as follows:

```
theta =
-170.10392    -0.40601     4.99799
```

So the equation is

```
predicted weight = -170.10392 - .406*age + 4.997*height
```

This is almost absolute minimum of the gradient, since the true results for
this problem if using PSPP (open source alternative of SPSS) are

```
predicted weight = -175.17 - .40*age + 5.07*height
```

Hope this helps to confirm the gradient descent algorithm works same for multiple linear regression and standard linear regression

Comment: Thank you so much for your response and quick help. I am not following you exactly here. I used the same logic for a single variable linear regression and it worked. Can you please elaborate ?

Comment: Thank you for explaining it again in detail. However, I am doing an assignment where I guess we need to add the code within the one function. Also, you added the theta zeros vector, I am still confused may be due to my lack of knowledge. Don't know why I can't do it within a single function though

Comment: @Gaurav: You can put the code for `gradient` into the other function, if you need to keep it as a single function.

Comment: Cris I am still confused can you help me explain what is wrong with my logic and why it needs an additional function to be defined as I see I am performing the similar logic as @Jose did.

Comment: Guys thanks a lot for the help I figured out my mistake it was with the feature normalization logic. I am able to run my code successfully and get all the values. Cheers :) so my above logic is correct

Comment: Say your response below, I'm not available to comment due to my poor reputation. You're right, feature scaling in learning is a black art. Citation below: bayerj (https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/2860/bayerj), How and why do normalization and feature scaling work?, URL (version: 2012-11-29): https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/44684 Also I was able to install Gnu Octave and have fixed the code above, so other readers can test this example which works without scaling though.